# Crash from __mh_execute_header

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I did an update to my app which is live since last yesterday and now some of my users seeing this crash. Normally I get at least an idea of what is causing the crash by reading the stack Trace, but this time I have no idea. I am also not very experienced in reading crash logs. This one is from Flurry and it s the only hint I have.

Does anyone has a tip what might cause the problem? What can I do to fix the crash? How to find out what is going wrong?

I am thankful for every little hint !

```
Full Stack Trace:
0   AppName                             0x10012e670 __mh_execute_header + 878192
1   StoreKit                            0x18997c9c0 <redacted> + 568
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x1972e5994 <redacted> + 24
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x1972e5954 <redacted> + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x1972ea20c __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
5   CoreFoundation                      0x184f53544 <redacted> + 12
6   CoreFoundation                      0x184f515ec <redacted> + 1492
7   CoreFoundation                      0x184e7cf74 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
8   GraphicsServices                    0x18e8d76fc _GSEventRunModal + 168
9   UIKit                               0x189a7ed94 _UIApplicationMain + 1488
10  AppName                             0x100131254 __mh_execute_header + 889428
11  libdyld.dylib                       0x197312a08 <redacted> + 4
```

EDIT

also found this in Flurry

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 0 in this backtrace has a generic symbol (__mh_execute_header) and a huge function offset, which just means your crash report is not symbolicated so it doesn't know a name to use.

See this technical note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Look under Symbolication for how to symbolicate the report using the .dSYM file you (hopefully) kept when you built the app for distribution.

Comment: hm, thx for help. My googling gave me also that hint Symbolication. Unfortunatly this seems very complicated... What I changed in the new version is that I iterate through all core data objects and give them an index number... I do this on first update launch in applicationdidfinishlaunching... I think the crashing has to do with that, it seems only people with many objects seeing this crash, and i read if you do something in didfinishwithlaunching that takes too long time the system will kill the app... Or it has to do with performing a icloud core data sync same time...

Comment: however, I just moved that iteration from didfinishlaunching to viewwillappear in my first viewcontroller... hope / guess this will help... it must have something to do with that because that s the only thing i changed in appdelegate and people seeing this crash are crashing while loading / showing the launch screen....

Comment: In "__mh_execute_header + 878192", the number is the function offset. It's saying your crash point is that far away from __mh_execute_header, which is really far.

Comment: applicationDidFinishLaunching will terminate if you take too long. If you're doing something that's locking up your main thread for too long, do it instead in a background task.

Comment: what I do there, my iteration must be done when my first viewcontroller ( a tableview) is showing... I do this only once and then never again.. so if it takes a moment and people seening my launch screen for some secs before the app starts, it s ok... so putting it in viewwillapear in my first viewcontroller seems to do what i want....!?

Comment: That seems like the right place to do it, yes. But I'd still do it in a background thread, and put up some kind of progress indicator on the screen (that prevents interaction with the UI) until it's finished. Your background job would then have a completion callback that removes the progress indicator and frees up the UI. That will prevent iOS from thinking your main thread is unresponsive.

Comment: yes, but: in this case my first viewcontroller is not showing untill my iteration has finished... the user sees the launch screen and can not interact with the app... And showing a progress indicator on the launchsreen is not possible as far as i know... and as i said, my iteration is only done once and then never again, so if people have to wait for some secs seeing the launchscreen is ok... wouldn t be if it s always the case, but it s only once when launching the update first time...

Comment: "will prevent iOS from thinking your main thread is unresponsive" - could iOS kill my app also in viewwillappear in a viewcontroller if it takes too long? thought it s only the case in didfinishlauncuing and some other appdelegatecallbacks... !?

Comment: Could you show me how to wrap a method in a background thread ? in objective-c please ? sorry for my noobness )

Comment: I don't think you'll get killed off in your view controller for locking up the main thread. Having said that, look at the docs for NSObject for the method -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: to fire off a background task. You can just set the delay to zero. But you'd have to set a flag or something to prevent your app from trying to do anything with your data until the background task is finished. What I do is put a "progress" indicator up so the user knows he has to wait a few seconds. Here's one: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: I googled background and found:dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // Perform async operation
        // Call your method/function here
        // Example:
        // NSString *result = [anObject calculateSomething];
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update UI
                    // Example:
                    // self.myLabel.text = result;
                });
    }); Thought I do my iteration inside there ??

Comment: That works too, but if you don't understand it it's probably best to start a whole new post with your question. :)